# Mobile website translation problem (losing language prefix)

Tags: i18n-l10n, theming

I have site translations that works with language prefix

m.mysite.com/ - default language (lithuanian) 
m.mysite.com/en - english 
...

If i translate site to foreign language and pushed menu button on mobile website, it redirects to the default language. 
For example, if I were in **m.mysite.com/en** (website translated in english) and pressed button "News" it redirects me to **m.mysite.com/news-page** that is in default language.

I should redirect to **m.mysite.com/*en*/news-page** that is translated in english and has language prefix /en/.

So, how to add language prefix to the link and redirect correctly (without losing current site translation)?

Answer (score 0):

We've come across a similar problem in our site on a desktop platform. So far, we've discovered the following about links in Drupal (for example, the `href` on an `<a>` tag in a Block Body):

- If you use a link without a preceding `/`, Drupal will replace the last url element with your link name (i.e. `mysite.com/en/area1/thing1` will become `mysite.com/en/area1/thing2` when a user clicks a link configured as `href="thing2"` on a page in `area1`).
- If you use a preceding `/` in your link, Drupal appends it to the domain directly (i.e. `href="/thing2"` directs to `mysite.com/thing2`).

We leveraged this to make language prefixes work, with limited success. As long as all our links are within the same uri path (i.e. all links on pages within `area1` go to `area1` pages), the language prefix is preserved. Once you try to leave that path, though (i.e. `href = "/area2/thing3"` on a page in `area1`), you must use the `/` and lose the language prefix. For those pages, you'll need to add URL aliases. We're still looking for a module/solution that saves us the time and effort of aliasing our menu system and cross links.

Note that in any case the base url (`mysite.com`) is preserved, so you should get the same results regardless of your platform (mobile or desktop).